# Soreness from not exercising

Tags: exercise

I exercise intensely for roughly 30 minutes 7 days a week. Monday, I got a sinus infection or cold or something, and because it was difficult to breathe, stopped exercising. I've gotten progressively more and more sore throughout the week, but my symptoms are diminishing. Is this from not exercising or possibly related the illness? If it's from not exercising, why would I be sore from inactivity?